# Creating unique index in pyarango arangodb

Tags: python, arangodb

I am trying to add an unique index to my collection.
I am writing code:

```
conn = Connection()
db = conn['textBook']
db['Users'].ensureHashIndex('word', unique = True);
```

(There is database 'textBook' with collection 'Users' existing.)

pyArango.theExceptions.CreationError: bad parameter. Errors: {u'errorMessage': u'bad parameter', u'errorNum': 10, u'code': 400, u'error': True}

It is occuring while creating Index in function _create  (raise CreationError(data['errorMessage'], data)   )

Which parameters are incorrect?

Comment: A hot guess would be that you need to specify the fields the index is created on as you need to in js: https://docs.arangodb.com/IndexHandling/Hash.html - this most probably maps to python like this: `{fields: [ "word"]}`; depending on the implementation only adding brackets [ ] to get a list may work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide fields in a list, so try this:

```
db['Users'].ensureHashIndex(['word'], unique = True)
```